# function that initiailzes a struct with a char - explain my warning?

Tags: c, initialization, char, structure

Does anyone know why the code below does not work with `char`s? It works with `int`s but when I want to use `char` to initialize structure it fails and gives a warning like:

```
warning: assignment makes integer from pointer without a cast
```

I don't know what this warning means.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct complex {
int re;
int im;
char name;
};

struct complex initialize (int k, int l, char nazwa)
{
    struct complex x;
    x.re = k;
    x.im = l;
    x.name= nazwa;
    return x;
}


int main ()
{
    struct complex e;
    struct complex f;
    int a;
    int b;
    char o;
    int c;
    int d;
    char p;
    a=5;
    b=6;
    o="t";
    e = initialize (a, b, o);
    c=8;
    d=3;
    p="u";
    f=initialize (c, d, p);
    printf("c1 = (%d,%d)\nc2 = (%d,%d)\n name 1=%s name 2=%s\n", e.re , e.im, f.re, f.im, e.name, f.name);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: you can't say `o="t"` you need to say `o='t'`. Your problem seems to have nothing to do with a struct or even a function.

Comment: use "rb"/"wb" flag, and `char` instead of `const char*`. but it is a new question.

Answer (score 5):

`"u"` is not a char. it is a string. a char array. you want `'u'` instead. But then you will have only one-character names, and you will need to replace the `%s` in `printf` with `%c`.

Unless you really want a string, and if so change your `char` in the struct to be `const char*`. The same goes the function parameter:

```
struct complex {
    int re;
    int im;
    const char* name;
};

struct complex initialize (int k, int l, const char* nazwa) {
...
}

const char* o;
const char* p;
```

Note that you can initialize variables, and structs. your code can be like this:

```
void print_complex(int n, struct complex c) {
    printf("c %d = (%d,%d)\n", n, c.re , c.im);
    printf("name=%s\n", c.name);
}

int main () {
    struct complex e = { 5, 6, "t" };
    struct complex f = { 8, 3, "u" };
    print_complex(1, e);
    print_complex(2, f);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: i tried in both ways, with string and char, program copmpiles but still stops working and brakes down

Comment: @Pepasek if you will change every `char` with `const char*` it should work.

Comment: Thanks now it works :) but how about storing these structures in the file? Now I have a promblem with that:

 

    FILE *fp= fopen("doc.txt", "a+");
    
            fwrite(&e, sizeof(e), 1, fp);
            fwrite(&f, sizeof(e), 1, fp);
    
            fclose(fp);
    
            fopen("doc.txt", "r");
    
            fread(&e, sizeof(e), 1, fp);
            printf("%d %d %s\n", e.re, e.im, e.name);
    
            fread(&f, sizeof(e), 1, fp);
            printf("%d %d %s\n", f.re, f.im, f.name);
    
    
            fclose(fp);

Comment: @Pepasek it doesn't work like that. this is a new question. before posting it, try to solve it yourself. Hint: it will be much easier if you will use `char`. Another hint: better not to jump to files before you are sure you understand the basics of the language.

Comment: Well I have the test tommorow, so I am quite nervous. I know it's probably easy but I'm quite tired of thinking what maybe wrong... Thank u @Elazar anyway

Comment: @Pepasek if you have a test, learn. don't post questions here. [Here's a light but important reading](http://c-faq.com/)